# Android AVD incompatible device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Android :*min version 13* 
       *target version 13*

Device **`QVGA(ADP2)`  320*480 `MDPI`**

When i try to start the application, it says no compatible device find.
What did i miss? Its just one activity and i just created it.
There is nothing in the XML 
files too. What should be the configuration of the **AVD** be?

Do i have to run the application only on tablets? cant i use mdpi or ldpi devices?

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smartcardholder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.smartcardholder.HomeScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Both are MDPI only but for tablet. you need to create one AVD for phones also.'

Answer (score 0):

```
(Are any of these AVDs running at the moment)?

If (yes) {
         simply start one of the AVDs.
         } 
else {
(Is the running AVD giving you any log on LogCat)?

 if (no) {
         restart ADB server
         }

 else {
      copy and paste your whole manifest file here,
     there might be be some other limitation specified in it.
      }

}
```

Comment: For example you might be emphasizing on using something like SD Card or Camera in your manifest but the AVDs are missing it in their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

Right click on a project you want to run in `package explorer`. Then go on `Run As -> Run Configurations`. One box open, In tabs click on `Target Tab` then check `Automatically Pick Compatible Device -> Select Device` on which you want to run your project. Click `Apply` then `Run`. Hope it works.

Comment: I did.But for some reason it says no device compatible.

Comment: Are you selecting any device from devices you created?